# Jquery AutoSuggestion doesnt update with new selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, fadein, fadeout

I wonder if anyone can help. I am using a script that autocompletes from a database, which is working fine apart from one issue I am wondering if someone maybe able to help me with.

When clicking on an autosuggestion it fills the textbox with the selection fine, but if you try to make another selection (by starting to type again), it doesnt fill the textbox with the new selection, it just retains the old selection.

Below is the code I have...

**rtsearch.php** (php removed to save space) that grabs the data to fill the html form & div:

```
<div class="display_box2" align="left">
<span class="name"><b><?php echo $country; ?></b>, <span class="bodyotxt"><?php echo $row['town']; ?></span></span>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

THE ACTUAL HTML FORM AUTOCOMPLETES:

```
<div><form action="<? $_SERVER['php self'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" class="form" id="form1" autocomplete="off">
 <input name="rt" type="text" class="search2" id="inputSearch2" value="" onclick="this.value='';" /></form>
      <div id="divResult2"></div>
 </div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".search2").keyup(function() 
{ 
var inputSearch2 = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'searchword='+ inputSearch2;
if(inputSearch2!='')
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "autocomplete/rtsearch.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#divResult2").html(html).show();
}
});
}return false;    
});

$("#divResult2, #divResult2 span").on("click",function(e){ 
//var $clicked = $(e.target);
if($(this).parent().attr("id")=="divResult2"){ var $clicked = $(this).parent(); }else{ var $clicked = $(e.currentTarget); }
var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
$('#inputSearch2').val(decoded);
});


$(document).on("click", function(e) { 
var $clicked = $(e.target);
if (! $clicked.hasClass("search2")){
$("#divResult2").fadeOut(); 
}
});
$('#inputSearch2').click(function(){
$("#divResult2").fadeIn();
});
});
```

I have gone through it and cannot seem to find the issue.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this

Comment: Instead of writing 'JQuery' everywhere why not just use $?

Comment: live() is deprecated, use on().

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` ?

Comment: OOoo maybe getting somewhere.... that actually worked (gosh you're good) but now it fades out almost instantly, you have to click quick but it definately works. any ideas why its fading out too quickly. When you click it for the first time, it appears and works perfectly, but if you click into the textbox again to make another selection it vanishes??

Answer (score 1):

maybe as simple as:

```
jQuery("#divResult2, #divResult2 span").on("click",...
```

Comment: Hiya I tried $("divResult2, #divResult2 span").on("click",function(e){ 
 var $clicked = $(e.target );
 var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
 var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
 $('#inputSearch2').val(decoded);
}); but it had gave me the original issue back, where the div was clickable but nothing happened when clicking the span.

Comment: maybe manipulating 

$clicked = $(e.target );

with something like:

if($(this).parent().attr("id")=="divResult2"){
var $clicked = $(this).parent();
}else{
var $clicked = $(e.currentTarget);
}

?

Comment: That kind of worked, well it sorted the fading out issue, but now theres another issue - although it isnt disappearing until i click another selection (which is great), it doesnt populate the textbox with the new selection. any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the original post to reflect what the JQ is now with your edit.

Comment: see what alert($name) and alert(decoded) spit out, depending where you click. That should help us find the problem